# box.com oauth2 "requesting permissions" dialog appears on every authentication

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, box-api

Our service, http://docmunch.com, is using box.com oauth to authenticate our users and authorize access to their box drives.  However, the "requesting permissions" dialog shows up every time a user authenticates.

With Google or Facebook (for other apps) this doesn't happen.  Once the user authorizes an app the oauth provider remembers the permission and doesn't keep asking.  However, box.com does not remember the authorization.  IS there any way to set up oauth so box only asks the user to authorize our app the first time?

Answer (score 0):

After you send the user through the OAuth flow, you receive an `access_token` and a `refresh_token`. You need to store the `refresh_token` for the particular user for future use. You don't need to send the user through the authorize flow every single time.

Comment: Before the use goes through the OAuth process, they aren't logged in though.  How would our app determine which refresh_token to send?  We're trying to just use Box accounts for authentication which is why we don't know which user's refresh_token to send.  It seems like this may be impossible with box.com as opposed to gmail and facebook.